# how to handle error and success message successfully?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Want show response body message on modal window. which is coming from server side. so below code is working fine when any error happens .but it's not working as expected when it is successfully executed(not able to see success message). i know i need to modify  **errorHandle** method. but  as a new comer to angular i am not able to figure it out best solution for it.can u please guide me.

**Registration.java**

```
         @RequestMapping(value = "/createRegistration",method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            public ResponseEntity createNewRegistration(@RequestBody Registration registration) {
              boolean isTrue=assetLiabilityService.createRegistration(registration);
              if(isTrue) {
                  return new ResponseEntity<>("User already Exist", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
              }
              else {
                  return new ResponseEntity<>("User Created Successfully",HttpStatus.OK);
              }
        }
```

**RegistrationService.ts**

```
        saveRegistration(regObj:any) {
            return this.http.post<any>('url',
              {
                name:regObj.name,
                password:regObj.password,
                email:regObj.email,

              }). pipe( share(),
              catchError(this.errorHandle));


                errorHandle(error) {
            let errorMessage = '';
            if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
              // Get client-side error
              errorMessage = error.error.message;
            } else {
              // Get server-side error
              errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
            }
            console.log(errorMessage);
            return throwError(errorMessage);
          }
```

**registrationCompnent.ts**

```
    save() {
        this.service.saveRegistration(this.regObj).subscribe(data=>{
        console.log("data from Server::"+data.text());
         },
         error => {
             console.log("Error::"+error);
         });
       }
```

Comment: What is `data` in response of HTTP call ? Can you provide it ? `data.text()` is incorrect

Comment: save() {
    this.service.saveRegistration(this.regObj).subscribe(data=>{
          this.isSuccess=true;
    },
      error => {
        this.isError=true;//
      });
  }      it always falling into error section even if it success http call.

Answer (score 1):

ofc this is not going to work.

```
produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
```

you are telling the application to produce a json result in the body.

```
return new ResponseEntity<>("User Created Successfully",HttpStatus.OK);
```

But you are returning a `ResponseEntity` containing plain text. If you wan't to return json, then return an object that can be serialized/deserialized into json.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this line

> console.log("data from Server::"+data.text());

you have written data.text() but in typescript there is no function called text(). if you want to convert your server JSON response into string use the following line.

> console.log("data from Server::"+JSON.stringify(data));

and if you want to access the text attribute of data object then use the following line

> console.log("data from Server::"+data.text);

Comment: i fixed it. nothing wrong in ui side . ResponseEntity is creating problem

Comment: you might have fixed it but this line is still wrong " data.text() " because text() function is not in javascript or typescript.